Why need to include template keyword when calling C++ functions?
Let's say that I have a class Analyzer whose analyze() function behaves differently depending on a template parameter B, which basically provides two versions of the analyze function:
class Analyzer {
 public:
  template <bool B>
  bool analyze(long l) {
    if constexpr(B) return (l > 0);
    else            return (l < 0);
  }
};

I found that sometimes I can directly call the version of analyze I like, but some other times I need to prepend the template keyword in front of it, resulting in a pretty weird syntax, for example, at the report2() function of the following code sample. My questions are:

Why does it work in report() without using the template keyword?
Why is it necessary to use the template keyword in report2()?

Note: the following code sample compiles successfully with g++ -std=c++17 ./source.cpp && ./a.out
#include <iostream>

class Analyzer {
 public:
  template <bool B>
  bool analyze(long l) {
    if constexpr(B) return (l > 0); 
    else            return (l < 0); 
  }
};

template <typename T>
class Base
{
 public:
  T val = 0;
  void report() {
    // Why do I not need template keyword here?
    std::cout << my_tool.analyze<false>(val) << std::endl;
  }

 protected:
  Analyzer my_tool;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
 public:
  void report2() {
    // Why do I need keyword template here?
    std::cout << (Base<T>::my_tool.template analyze<true>(Base<T>::val)) << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto b = Base<int>();
  b.val = 10; 
  b.report();

  auto d = Derived<long>();
  d.val = 10; 
  d.report();
  d.report2();
}


A little information from compilers if function report2 doesn't have the template keyword, though it doesn't help much to understand my questions...

gcc reports invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘bool’ to binary ‘operator<’
clang reports missing 'template' keyword prior to dependent template name 'analyze'

